# How `sequenceA` works

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm new to Haskell and trying to understand how does this work?

```
sequenceA [(+3),(+2),(+1)] 3
```

I have started from the definition

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]  
sequenceA [] = pure []  
sequenceA (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

And then  unfolded recursion into this

```
(:) <$> (+3) <*> $ (:) <$> (+2) <*> $ (:) <$> (+1) <*> pure [] 
(:) <$> (+3) <*> $ (:) <$> (+2) <*> $ (:) <$> (+1) <*> []
```

But here i don't understand for which applicative functor operator `<*>` will be called, for `((->) r)` or for `[]`

```
(:) <$> (+1) <*> []
```

Can somebody go step by step and parse `sequenceA [(+3),(+2),(+1)] 3` step by step? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, this is obfuscated code that hopefully no one would ever write in a real program. More natural would be `map ($ 3) [(+3),(+2),(+1)]`.

Comment: @ReidBarton, or `[(+3),(+2),(+1)] <*> [3]`, or much better, `(3+) <$> [3,2,1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is using `instance Applicative ((->) a)`.

Try this in ghci:

```
Prelude> :t [(+3),(+2),(+1)]
[(+3),(+2),(+1)] :: Num a => [a -> a]

Prelude> :t sequenceA
sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

and pattern match the argument type: `t = [], f = (->) a`
and the Applicative constraint is on f.

Comment: so `(+3)` is kinda an instance of `(->) a`

Comment: `(-> a)` is a partially applied type contructor. You could say that `(+3)` is compatible with `(-> a)`. You can check this in ghci:
`:t (+3) :: Num a => (->) a a`

Answer (score 10):

This can be seen from the type of sequenceA:

`sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`

The argument's outer type has to be a `Traverable`, and its inner type has to be `Applicative`.

Now, when you give sequenceA a list of functions `(Num a) => [a -> a]` the list will be the `Traversable`, and the things inside the list should be  `Applicative`. Therefore, it uses the applicative instance for functions.

So when you apply sequenceA to `[(+3),(+2),(+1)]`, the following computation is built:

```
sequenceA [(+3),(+2),(+1)] = (:) <$> (+3) <*> sequenceA [(+2),(+1)]
sequenceA [(+2),(+1)]      = (:) <$> (+2) <*> sequenceA [(+1)]
sequenceA [(+1)]           = (:) <$> (+1) <*> sequenceA []
sequenceA []               = pure []
```

Let's look at the last line. `pure []` takes an empty list and puts it inside some applicative structure. As we've just seen, the applicative structure in this case is `((->) r)`. Because of this, `sequenceA [] = pure [] = const []`.

Now, line 3 can be written as:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = (:) <$> (+1) <*> const []
```

Combining functions this way with `<$>` and `<*>` results in parallel application. `(+1)` and `const []` are both applied to the same argument, and the results are combined using `(:)`

Therefore `sequenceA [(+1)]` returns a function that takes a `Num a => a` type value, applies `(+1)` to it, and then prepends the result to an empty list, `\x -> (:) ((1+) x) (const [] x)` = `\x -> [(+1) x]`.

This concept can be extended further to `sequenceA [(+3), (+2), (+1)]`. It results in a function that takes one argument, applies all three functions to that argument, and combines the three results with `(:)` collecting them in a list: `\x -> [(+3) x, (+2) x, (+1) x]`.

Comment: Sorry, what does const mean in `const []`.

Comment: It is a functuion defined as: `const a b = a`
So when you evaluate `const []` it returns a function that always produces an empty list as result, regardless of what argument you pass to that function.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has trouble accepting that an argument to `sequenceA [(+1)]` just magically applies itself to BOTH `(+1)` and `const []`, this is for you. It was the only sticking point for me after realizing that `pure [] = const []`.

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = (:) <$> (+1) <*> const []
```

Using lambdas (so we can explicitly show and move things around when we start treating function application like a functor and an applicative):

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = \b c -> ( (:) b c ) <$> ( \a -> (+1) a ) <*> ( \a -> const [] a )
```

Both `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` are infixl 4. Which means we read and evaluate from left to right, i.e. we start with `(<$>)`.

Where `(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

The effect of `<$>` is to pluck `(+1)` out of it's wrapper `((->) r)`, OR `\a ->` from our lambda code, and apply it to `\b c -> ( (:) b c )` where it will take the place of `b`, then re-apply the wrapper (that's the `\a` that appears after the equals sign on the line below):

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = \a c -> ( (:) ((+1) a) c ) <*> ( \a -> const [] a )
```

Notice that `(:)` is still waiting for an argument `c`, and `(+1)` is still waiting for an `a`. Now, we get to the applicative part.

Remember that: `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. Our `f` here is the function application `\a ->`.

Both sides now have the same wrapper, namely `\a ->`. *I'm keeping the `a`'s in there to remind us where the `a`'s will be applied later, so it does become a little pseudo-y here. The function application will be connected back up in just a jiffy*. Both functions depend on the same `a`, precisely because they had the same function application wrapper i.e. an applicative. Without their `\a ->` wrappers (thanks to `<*>`), it goes like this:

```
( \c -> ( (:) ((+1) a) c ) ) (const [] a)

= ( (:) ((+1) a) (const [] a) ) -- Ignore those a's, they're placeholders.
```

Now, the very last thing that `<*>` does is to pop this result back into it's wrapper `\a ->`:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = \a -> ( (:) ((+1) a) (const [] a) )
```

Sugaring this up a little bit gives:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] = \a -> (+1) a : const [] a
```

See! It makes perfect sense that an argument to `sequenceA [(+1)]` goes to both `(+1)` and `const`. Applying a 2, for instance, gives:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] 2 = (+1) 2 : const [] 2
```

Remember that `const a b :: a -> b -> a`, and therefore just ignores it's input:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] 2 = 3 : []
```

OR, more sweetly:

```
sequenceA [(+1)] 2 = [3]
```