# What does `sequenceA (replicate n getChar)` do?

Tags: haskell, applicative

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA []     = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

which can be used for example:

```
getChars :: Int -> IO String
getChars n = sequenceA (replicate n getChar)
```

`replicate n getChar` outputs `[getChar, getChar, ...]` of type `[IO Char]`.

What does `sequenceA (replicate n getChar)` do ?

In general what does `sequenceA` do?

Comment: What's with the random spacing?

Comment: The code uses tabs in _every single space_. As a general rule, tabs break the Haskell parser, so you shouldn't use them _at all_. I've edited the code to use spaces and more consistent spacing in general.

Comment: `sequenceA` is described and explained in the [prelude documentation on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequenceA) as well as [various past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629132/how-sequencea-works). This question is lacking in research effort.

Comment: according to what you wrote in a recent question, `sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs = liftA2 (:) x (sequenceA xs) = [ x : xs | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]`. thus `sequenceA (replicate 3 getChar) = [ x : xs | x <- getChar, xs <- sequenceA [getChar,getChar]] = [[x,y,z] | x <- getChar, y <- getChar, z <- getChar]`. this uses MonadComprehensions.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks. (1) How did you get `liftA2 (:) x (sequenceA xs) = [ x : xs | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]`? (2)  What is monad comprehension?

Comment: @Tim For (2), it’s a language extension allowing list comprehensions to be used for arbitrary monads. As for (1), it’s a simple equivalence originating from the definitions of `liftA2` and monad comprehensions.

Comment: @bradrn Is the result  of monad comprehension a list? Since it is a generalization of list comprehension, is it correct that it shouldn't output list? But `[ x : xs | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]` seems to be a list.

Comment: @Tim The result of a monad comprehension is whatever monad you’re using. If `x` and `xs` are lists, then `[ x : xs | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]` will also be a list. If they’re some other monad, the output will also be that monad.

Comment: @bradrn So `[...]` in `[ x : xs | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]` doesn't necessarily mean list, and different from `[...]` (which represents a list) in Haskell language?

Comment: @Tim It depends. List comprehensions were originally designed only for lists, so I presume that `[...]` originally denoted that it was a _list_ comprehension. By default, this is what Haskell uses. However, if you enable the `MonadComprehensions` extension, then you can use the same syntax for arbitrary monads. So if you use that extension, `[...]` is best thought of as just part of the syntax than having any particular meaning.

Comment: @Tim "Is the result of monad comprehension a list?" why don't you try `GHCi> :set -XMonadComprehensions` ; `GHCi> :t [[x,y,z] | x <- getChar, y <- getChar, z <- getChar]` and find out? -- Googling ["MonadComprehensions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MonadComprehensions) leads to e.g. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/monad-comprehensions.

Comment: then there's [the original paper](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/WadlerMonads.pdf) and [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=parallellist#monad-comprehensions).

Comment: as to the *why*, `pure (:) <*> x = (:) <$> x = fmap (:) x` and hence `pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs = fmap (:) x <*> sequenceA xs = {- by def of <*> -} do { fx <- fmap (:) x ; xs <- sequenceA xs; return fx xs } = do { x <- x ; let fx = (:) x ; xs <- sequenceA xs; return fx xs } = do { x <- x ; xs <- sequenceA xs; return (x : xs) } = [ (x : xs) | x <- x, xs <- sequenceA xs]`. All the above of course only holds for such Applicative Functors that are also Monads. Such that are not, have to implement it directly. But it is nevertheless illuminating to see these translations, I think.

Answer (score 3):

`sequenceA (replicate n getChar)` will wait for `n` characters from standard input and return them as `String` (list of `Char`) wrapped into `IO`. `sequenceA` will just evaluate (run in case of IO) the actions in the traversable and collect the results.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes you know what an `Applicative` is; if you don’t, [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) may be a useful resource.)

Roughly speaking, `sequenceA` is a method of taking several `Applicative` values and running them. To start, let’s have a look at its type signature. You’ve defined a restricted version, but the full type signature is:

```hs
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

In general, Haskell allows you to learn a lot about a function from its type signature alone, and this is no exception. To start, let’s have a look at its input and output: it takes as input a `Traversable` containing `Applicative` elements, and returns an `Applicative` containing `Traversible` elements.

Now, how can we get from `t (f a)` to `f (t a)`? This may be easier to understand if you *specialise* `t` to `[]`, as that is an instance of `Traversible`:

```hs
sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
```

Now this starts to make more sense: given a list of `f a`s, extract the `a`s and return them as a list. The idea is that a value of type `f x`, where `f` is an `Applicative`, is an *effectful value*: a value which could potentially have some side-effects, but then returns a value of type `x`. So `sequenceA` acts to **accumulate** effects: if you have a list of effectful values `[f a]`, then `sequenceA` takes each `f a` in sequence, runs its effect, then returns all the `a`s together. It returns these values as an effectful list, since to return `[a]` it has to run the effects inside the original list.

Now let’s go back to the original definition:

```hs
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

We can interpret this in the same way: given a set of effectful values inside a `Traversible` data structure, `sequenceA` returns an effectful value created by running all the effects inside the `Traversible` in turn, then taking the return value thus generated and putting it back inside the `Traversible`. The idea of ‘in turn’ is very important: in some sense, the `Traversible` instance (and hence `sequenceA`, as one of its methods) *creates* the idea of an order inside a data structure, since there aren’t really any other Haskell functions which iterate over a data structure in some particular order.

Now, we can finally understand your example! Let’s consider what `sequenceA (replicate n getChar)` does:

- As you noted, `replicate n getChar` repeats a list of `[getChar, getChar, ..., getChar]` *n* times.
- From the above description:

  > `sequenceA` returns an effectful value created by running all the effects inside the `Traversible` in turn, then taking the return value thus generated and putting it back inside the `Traversible`.

  So here, we take the list of `getChar`s, run each effectful value (which has the effect of getting a character from the user and returning it), then taking the return value (i.e. the user’s character) and putting it back inside the `Traversible` (i.e. putting the return values back in a list).

So `sequenceA (replicate n getChar)` just gets *n* characters from the user, then returns them in a list.

It’s worth noting that this is far from the only use for `sequenceA`. A small sample:

- The `Applicative` instance for lists takes each pair in turn from the give lists. For instance, `(,) <$> [1,2] <*> ['a','b']` returns `[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]`. So `sequenceA [list1, list2, ...]` gets all combinations of elements i.e. the cartesian produce! For example, `sequenceA [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f']]` ‘runs’ the applicative by returning each combination, and then puts the results back in a list, giving `["ace","acf","ade","adf","bce","bcf","bde","bdf"]`.
- In general, any time you have a collection of effects you want to run, you should be reaching for `sequenceA`. (Or its close relative `traverse`.) For example, recently I was writing a cellular automaton simulation program, and I had ended up with a data structure representing a grid with random elements. Since I was using the `MonadRandom` package, my randomness was represented as an `Applicative`, so I could use `sequenceA` to run each random value in turn and turn a ‘grid of random values’ into a ‘random grid of values’, which was much easier to work with.